# Read a file with Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I've been looking around, and there are lots of methods to do this. Unfortunately, these are outdated and have been made impossible with browser updates. There is a lot of cross-origin stuff too, and the best thing I could find was [this](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/191/how-to-read-a-computer-file-using-javascript-in-the-browser). Is there any way to access a file without using the file input type, and just using text instead? Eg: I input C:\Users\User\Desktop\myLibraries\jquery.min.js and it returns the code. I have no idea where to start on this, and all other methods are outdated.

Comment: As meagar said, browsers can't do this without the user giving permission and a file location (e.g. through a button click).  However, Node.Js exists for running JS on the desktop.  In this case, you would use the `fs` module, specifically `fs.readFile` or `fs.readFileSync`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no safe cross-browser way to do this. Any way that you find that allows you to do this would be considered an exploit, and browser manufacturers would close it.

Your page is not able to access arbitrary files on your user's computers, just like other pages are not allowed to access arbitrary files on *your* computer, which I'm sure you're thankful for.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! This had me very confused for a few months.